# Inconsistent data.table assignment by reference behaviour

Tags: r, data.table

When assigning by reference with a `data.table` using a column from a second `data.table`, the results are inconsistent. When there are no matches by the key columns of both `data.table`s, it appears the assigment expression `y := y` is totally ignored - not even `NA`s are returned.

```
library(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(id = 1:2, x = 3:4, key = "id")
dt2 <- data.table(id = 3:4, y = 5:6, key = "id")
print(dt1[dt2, y := y])
##    id x     # Would have also expected column:   y
## 1:  1 3     #                                   NA
## 2:  2 4     #                                   NA
```

However, when there is a partial match, non-matching columns have a placeholder `NA`.

```
dt2[, id := 2:3]
print(dt1[dt2, y := y])
##    id x  y
## 1:  1 3 NA    # <-- placeholder NA here
## 2:  2 4  5
```

This wreaks havoc on later code that assumes a `y` column exists in all cases. Otherwise I keep having to write cumbersome additional checks to take into account both cases.

Is there an elegant way around this inconsistency?

Comment: You could create the `y` column first... `dt1[, y:=NA_integer_];dt1[dt2, y:=y][]`

Comment: I think the most elegant way is to submit a feature request on github ;)

Comment: @eddi - thanks. See https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/759

Comment: OTOH when `y` isn't in the joined table, I notice I made a mistake in my code more quickly. But yes what you suggested is probably better as it's more robust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [this recent commit](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/ee7c24716348cc6b51f22b21377530d2df3ba9c7), this issue, [#759](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/759), is now fixed in v1.9.7. It works as expected when `nomatch=NA` (the current default).

```
require(data.table)
dt1 <- data.table(id = 1:2, x = 3:4, key = "id")
dt2 <- data.table(id = 3:4, y = 5:6, key = "id")
dt1[dt2, y := y][]
#    id x  y
# 1:  1 3 NA
# 2:  2 4 NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Using merge works:

```
> dt3 <- merge(dt1, dt2, by='id', all.x=TRUE)
> dt3
   id x  y
1:  1 3 NA
2:  2 4 NA
```